# What exactly is considered a "low quality" question?

Tags: support

Lately I have come across several questions where the users have posted code that has trivial syntax errors such as missing a semicolon `;`.

And I got a feeling that it is not that they have not got it if they have reviewed their questions once before posting on SO.

I want to flag them **low quality** but since the language defining this term goes something like this `severe content problems...`, I am never sure if I am flagging correctly.

So, first, should such trivial mistakes considered low quality and if yes, I think the definition for low quality should be modified a bit!

These made me lose my temper today:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836299/c-reading-if-char-being-typed-is-in-array-and-printing-something-else and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883318/else-is-unexpected

Comment: That's not "very low quality", that's a typo. Comment and ask them to fix it, or edit minor things in yourself. Trivial mistakes do not a poor answer make.

Comment: Note that the flag is not "low quality", it's "*very* low quality". The former feels a whole lot different than the latter. Even if I hadn't read the extended description you mention above, I'd know that a missing semicolon doesn't qualify.

Comment: I think asking them to fix it is ok as if I edit the question that is the solution.

Comment: Related: [When to use the flag "low quality"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216107/238706)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "Very Low Quality" question is one that *cannot be salvaged by editing.*  That means that the quality problems are so severe that you can't figure out what the OP's intent is.

Raising a flag is akin to requesting a close.  As irate as I get over spelling and grammatical errors (they are an indicator of laziness if they occur too frequently), they are seldom a valid reason to close, unless they make the question unintelligible.

Comment: is there an alternative way to deal with such mistakes as `missing semicolons` or it is a burden destined for reviewers and moderators. :P

Comment: If it doesn't change the meaning of the question, @Ankit (maybe the missing semicolon is the cause of all the OP's problems, after all), then *fix it*!

Comment: Hi Robert, I think it is important to recognize that sometimes spelling and grammar issues are due to language barriers/education/opportunities and are not *always* an indicator of laziness. If the person is from a native English speaking country, then I'm inclined to agree; otherwise, it may be because he/she is doing the best he/she can. I want to emphasize that we should all use judgement when reviewing posts with these particular issues, as I've seen some of them turn around into decent questions with some editing.